# Get associated minimum

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the following condition:
Each LID is associated with multiple BID and each BID has an AvgTrustValue.
I wish to find a BID with the lowest AvgTrustValue for each LID

I've done the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LID, T1.BID, AvgTrustValue
FROM Loans T1, Repayments T2, 
    (SELECT BID, AVG(trust_value) As AvgTrustValue
    FROM Assign
    GROUP BY BID) T3
WHERE T1.LoanID = T2.LoanID
AND T1.BID = T3.BID
ORDER BY LID
```

However it only gives me the following:

```
|   LID    |    BID    |
|S2262450A | S7444319C | 82
|S2848191X | S7611209X | 76
|S2848191X | S9981233W | 100
|S4495282I | S7444319C | 82
|S4792394D | S7444319C | 82
|S4792394D | S7611209X | 76
|S7145303Q | S7611209X | 76
|S7173102K | S7444319C | 82
```

What I wish to get is the following:

```
|   LID    |    BID    |
|S2262450A | S7444319C | 82
|S2848191X | S7611209X | 76
|S4495282I | S7444319C | 82
|S4792394D | S7611209X | 76
|S7145303Q | S7611209X | 76
|S7173102K | S7444319C | 82
```

I have also tried the following but failed:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LID, T1.BID, min(AvgTrustValue)
FROM Loans T1, Repayments T2, 
    (SELECT BID, AVG(trust_value) As AvgTrustValue
    FROM Assign
    GROUP BY BID) T3
WHERE T1.LoanID = T2.LoanID
AND T1.BID = T3.BID
GROUP BY LID
ORDER BY LID
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use window function `row_number` to get one row per lid with least AvgTrustValue:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over (
            partition by lid order by AvgTrustValue
            ) as rn
    from your_table t
    ) t
where rn = 1;
```

Or use `TOP with ties`:

```
select top 1 with ties *
from your_table
order by row_number() over (
        partition by lid order by AvgTrustValue
        );
```

Comment: I like the WITH TIES option ... always looks cleaner to me +1

Comment: Thank you. The TOP WITH TIES solution is gorgeous.

Answer (score 0):

I think 'not exists' would be OK, too

select lid,bid,avgvalue from your_table a 
where not exists (select 1 from your_table where lid=a.lid and avgvalue>a.avgvalue)